# Regex matching hyphen and comma and only in between

Tags: java, regex

I am checking for a string using regex.

**The rule is :**

The String can,

contain any digits, hyphen and comma

Hyphen and Comma should be only in-between the digits.  It should not in the beginning or the end of the string.

Comma is optional.  Hyphen is compulsory

For Example,

**Valid :**

```
10-20
10-20-3
10-20,3
```

**InValid :**

```
10
-10
,10
10-20,
10-20-
10,20
```

**The code I tried so far:**

```
[0-9,-]+
```

*can someone suggest how to check the coma and hyphen should not be in the beginning or end of the string and also the above conditions?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
[0-9][0-9,-]*-[0-9,-]*[0-9]
```

What this means is that the string must:

- Starts and ends in a digit
- Contains at least one dash in the middle
- after the first digit and before the dash there's zero or more `[0-9,-]` characters
- between the dash and the last digit there's zero or more `[0-9,-]` characters

Answer (score 1):

you should try this

```
[0-9][0-9,\-]*-[0-9,\-]*[0-9]
```

I think the hyphen needs to be backslashed in the character class

Answer (score 0):

The expression should include `^` or `\A` at the beginning and `$` or `\z` at end otherwise the expression would also match the invalid string like:

```
,10
20-
-34
```

**So the expression should be :**

```
^[0-9][0-9,-]*-[0-9,-]*[0-9]$
```